# Parse Json containing a list

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a trouble finding a way how to parse this `JSON`.

```
{
  "token":"3c7dbdc69c02eb365b2900d3e5027a08c79fce43",
  "profiles":["User","PartnerUser"],
  "status":"OK"
}
```

Plz,i need your hepl. I find atrouble with this `"profiles":["User","PartnerUser"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class that represent that json file and then parse it via [GSon](https://github.com/google/gson) library:

Possible scenario:

**Result.class**

```
public class Result{
  String token;
  List<String> profiles;
  String status;

  //getter and setter
}
```

to parse json:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Result result = gson.fromJson(json, Result.class);

ArrayList<String> profiles = new ArrayList();
profiles = result.getProfiles();
```

check [this](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some library to perform JSON parsing?
If not, you can use the [getJSONArray(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String)) method passing "profiles" as name of the array

Comment: here is my code, the problem is that msg.iterator dosn't work : JSONArray msg = jObj.getJSONArray("profiles");

                   
                    System.out.println(msg);


                     Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
                     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                      System.out.println(iterator.next());
                      }

Comment: i want to extract profiles types, in this case: User,PartnerUser.

Comment: You should use a foreach scanning the entire JSONArray and retrieving the single object via the JSONArray#get(int index) method.

Comment: Yeah, GSON is very much better then parsing manually a JSON :)